# How to circumvent full system update to install just 'build-essentials'?

Tags: installation, update-manager, install-from-source

After I install a fresh copy of Ubuntu (version 12.04), I need to install `build-essentials`. To do so, in the terminal I have to run this first:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

before I'm able to install `build-essentials`.

These two commands take a **lot** of time and install many things.

Is there a way to install `build-essentials` without running these two commands, or a way that these two commands don't install all the updates and hence will take less time?

Comment: problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package manager has to be updated once so it knows the package lists (The catalogue of packages that are available). Only then can you install any new package in a new installation.

To avoid bandwidth consumption, please do `sudo apt-get update` at the least, so your computer knows where to get the packages from. Upgrade can be avoided, unless you get errors when you do the next step: `sudo apt-get install build-essentials`.

You might also want to install `binutils-gold` if you are compiling OpenGL or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Build Essentials packages is part of compiling tools: [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

Thus, users **strongly recommended** to update and upgrade their distributions to minimize compiler/packager(installer) errors.

Hence the fact, even though you're do not planned to compile, you're need to be sure that your packagers and de-packagers is working right way.